# Can't get createAsyncThunk to fire from connected React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to use createAsyncThunk for some API calls but I can't seem to get it to work. My normal actions are working, so I must be connecting my component to redux correctly, but there's something different about createAsyncThunk I'm missing. Calling this.props.checkSession() from below does nothing. None of the console.logs inside checkSession are printed an fetch() never hits the server.

AppScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkSession } from './actions';
import { setToken } from './reducer';

class AppScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounted")
    this.props.checkSession();
    console.log("Moving on")
    if (!this.props.loading && !this.props.auth_token) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth')
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>You're in! {this.props.auth_token}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.app.user,
    auth_token: state.app.auth_token,
    loading: state.app.loading,
    error: state.app.error
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkSession: () => dispatch(checkSession),
    setToken: token => dispatch(setToken(token))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppScreen);
```

Actions

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { API_URL, ENDPOINTS } from "./../constants";

export const checkSession = createAsyncThunk("checkSession", (thunkAPI) => {
  console.log("Running")
  let body = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({auth_token: thunkAPI.getState().app.auth_token})
  }

  console.log("Checking session.")

  return fetch(`${API_URL}${ENDPOINTS.CHECK_SESSION}`, body)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(`API hit: ${response.ok}`)
      if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => json);
});
```

Reducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { checkSession } from "./actions"

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState: {
    loading: true,
    auth_token: "",
    error: "",
    user: {}
  },
  reducers: {
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      state.auth_token = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [checkSession.pending]: state => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [checkSession.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [checkSession.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
      state.auth_token = action.payload.auth_token;
    }
  }
});

export const { setToken } = appSlice.actions;
export const appReducer = appSlice.reducer;
```

Store

```
import { appReducer } from "./App/reducer";
import { authReducer } from "./Auth/reducer";
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const middleware = [
  ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
]

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    app: appReducer,
    auth: authReducer
  },
  middleware,
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `checkSession` wrong.  It should be `dispatch(checkSession())`.

That said, you should also be using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), like this:

```js
const mapDispatch = {checkSession, setToken};
```